# Checking to see if the caption button was clicked on google meet using a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently making a chrome extension for google meet and am trying to detect if the caption button was clicked. I currently have this code:

```
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe fzRBVc tmJved xHd4Cb rmHNDe Qr8aE')[0];

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
console.log('clicked');
  
});
```

This is working if I directly inject it into the console but not from the chrome extension. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When are you running this code in the extension? Try using `"run_at": "document_end"` or the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: I'm running this in the background.js file which is also in the manifest as a    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }

Comment: Just tried this "content_scripts":[{
    "js": ["background.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end" 
  }]                                                                                                                                                 It didnt work and i got this error                                                                       
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')